# Change property grid collection display

Tags: .net, collections, propertygrid

How can I change the **(Collection)** text displayed on the right column for a collection property in a property grid?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [TypeConverterAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverterattribute) with a custom [TypeConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverter), something like this:

```
public class Sample
{
    public Sample()
    {
        Ints = new List<int>();
    }

    [TypeConverter(typeof(MyConverter))]
    public List<int> Ints { get; }
}

public class MyConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(string))
            return "Hello world";

        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
}
```